# Can somebody explain how this state machine program works?

Tags: c

I cannot understand how this program works; can somebody explain?
I know that it is connected with state machine, but I do not understand how state machine works.

```
void abba();

int main()
{
    printf("Enter 10 characters, a or b.\n");
    abba();

    return 0;
}

void abba() 
{
    int x = 0;
    char  a;

    while ((scanf_s("%c", &a) == 1) && (a == 'a' || a == 'b')) {
        switch (x) {
        case 0:
            if (a == 'a')
                x = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            if (a == 'b')
                x = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (a == 'b')
                x = 3;
            else
                x = 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (a == 'b')
                x = 0;
            else {
                puts("abba is found !");
                x = 4;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try following the logic "by hand", using, e.g., "ababbabbab"?

Comment: The comment about '10 characters' in the `main()` function is not enforced.  There are no function prototypes in the code, only function declarations.  The functions should be declared `void abba(void);` etc to enforce a prototype.

Comment: (Please use spoilers in direct answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the state machine for your code.
[image]

As you see there are 4 states.

*Explanation for the each states*

> 1. **state 0 -** If you receives `char a` you move to state 1 else you stay in the state 0.
> 2. **state 1** - If you receives `char b` you move to state 2 else you stay in the state 1.
> 3. **state 2** - If you receives `char b` you move to state 3 else you go back to state 1 from there again you need to read `bb` to reach state
>      3.
> 4. **state 3** - If  you receives `char a` you read complete `abba` else you need to read the input from the beginning.

Comment: Nit-picking: when it goes into state 4, it continues reading a's and b's until it reads something that isn't an a or a b.